# Client-side relative addressing and allowing no trailing slash in application URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this strange issue with ASP.NET Core 3.1 that I don't have in my ASP.NET 4 applications where if I access my application via

`http://example.com/Application/`

then everything works ok, but if I try to go to

`http://example.com/Application` (no trailing slash)

then client-side relative addresses resolve to `http://example.com/Resource` instead of `http://example.com/Application/Resource`.

I had similar issues referring to the root of the application. For example, `/Resource` seems to mean relative to the domain, and so yields `http://example.com/Resource`. `Resource` by itself correctly yields `http://example.com/Application/Resource`. But how to refer to the "root" itself? Redirecting to the empty string seems to refresh the page instead of redirecting to the application root.

I got around that by using `.`, and by using `./Resource` instead of `Resource`. This seems to work in almost all cases, except when accessing the application without the trailing slash.

When accessing `http://example.com/Application`, AJAX calls targeting URLs of the form `./Method?handler=name` result in the request `http://example.com/Method?handler=name` (missing the `Application` part of the path).

How do I get client-side relative addresses to consistently refer to the correct application root address? Or is it possible that this is normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the base url in your main template (`_Layout.cshtml` in ASP.NET Core MVC) to the application path.

In `_Layout.cshtml` add

```
<base href="~/"/>
```

`~/` is your applications path (also called web root) that ASP.NET Core will replace with `http://example.com/Application`. Generally if you need application relative paths you should always do `<a href="~/app/relative/path"></a>`.

That may proof a bit difficult when static json files are involved, so `<base href="..."/>` should work in this cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function stripSlashEnds(url){
  return url.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
}
console.log(stripSlashEnds('http://example.com/Application/')+'/'+stripSlashEnds('/anotherFile/'));
console.log(stripSlashEnds('http://example.com/Application')+'/'+stripSlashEnds('/anotherFile'));
```

Notice that `stripSlashEnds` just removes forward lashes from the beginning and end of a String. You'll have to `+'/'` add one.